# How to clear NSTextView selection without it becoming first responder?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nstextview

I have a basic Cocoa app with a number of `NSTextView`s. When a text view loses focus (i.e. resigns its first responder status), I'd like to clear its selection.

My strategy was to extend `NSTextView` and override `resignFirstResponder()`:

```
override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {

    // Both result in the text view becoming first responder again:
    clearSelection(nil)
    setSelectedRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))

    return super.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

The problem is that calling `clearSelection()` and `setSelectedRange()` both cause the text view to become first responder again.

Is there a way to clear the selection without it becoming the first responder?

I tried to also override `acceptsFirstResponder` and temporarily return `false`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I tried your code, `clearSelection` doesn't compile, `setSelectedRange` works without changing the first responder.

Answer (score 1):

Met the same issue today and found the solution

You can do `setSelectedRange` in `NSTextView`'s delegate method `textDidEndEditing` and it wouldn't cause `NSTextView` become first responder.

```
class TextView: NSTextView {
    init() {
        self.delegate = self
        ....
    }
    ....
}

extension TextView: NSTextViewDelegate {
    public func textDidEndEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
        setSelectedRange(NSMakeRange(string.count, 0))
    }
}
```